# how to hide the error message?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

please help solve the problem.

a [form](http://jsfiddle.net/AnSu5/23/). inscription "You break my heart" appears immediately after downloading a form. but I need to download the form immediately after this line was not. and that it appeared only after the user tried to enter text

```
<div ng-app="">
    <form name="LovelyForm">
        <input type="email" name="LovelyEmail" ng-model="email" required />
        <br>
        <span ng-show="LovelyForm.LovelyEmail.$invalid">You break my heart</span>    
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: yes they are. it is this

Comment: Hey you can check $prisitne or $dirty at the time of first loading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following for the ng-show:

```
 LovelyForm.LovelyEmail.$dirty && LovelyForm.LovelyEmail.$invalid
```

dirty fires the check, when user has input something.

Answer (score 0):

You need $pristine check

```
<span ng-show="LovelyForm.LovelyEmail.$invalid && !LovelyForm.LovelyEmail.$pristine">You break my heart</span>
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/exyxudq4/)